# tag problem with tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinyMCE to create a message and email in my php application.

However when I use tinyMCE email comes with tags like,

```
<p>This is message</p>
```

If I don't use tinyMCE, message is sent without tag.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to compose a Mail in TinyMCE. When TinyMCE has edited the content, it is in HTML rather than plain text format. If you send HTML code in a plain text mail, the result is what you describe: The tags become visible in the content instead of formatting it.

You need to send the contents as HTML mail. There are several ways to do this. The easiest is to use a mailer class like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) that does all the heavy lifting for you.